# Detecting an image is fully loaded from a directive, where the directive is not applied to the image element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

there are many examples in SO on how we can use an angular directive to know when an image is loaded. The examples describe a directive that is directly applied to the img element like so:

```
<img ng-src="myimage.jpg" my-great-directive />
```

And then in the  directive "my-great-directive"

we can do an:

```
element.bind("load" , function(e){ }
```

And i works great.

However, what if the construct is like this:

```
<div my-great-directive>
  <img ng-src="myimage.jpg" />
</div>
```

Within my-great-directive, how do I bind to the inside image loaded event?

This is not really a theoretical problem for me. I am using a 3rd party slider called angular-carousel-slider that wraps around like so:

```
<ul rn-carousel  rn-carousel-buffered
                    rn-carousel-index="mycarousel.index"
                    rn-carousel-auto-slide="0.3" rn-carousel-pause-on-hover >
   <li ng-repeat="slide in slides">
       <img ng-src="{{eventBasePath}}{{slide.img}}?rand={{rand}}"/>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to modify its code so that it does not slide to the next image unless the current image is fully loaded (to avoid the situation of a fast slider half loading images and moving to the next). I'm stuck on how I can trap this image loaded event inside the directive. Doing `element.bind("load")` does not work as the directive is not applied to the image element.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this working demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xqywjghp/)

Use [`anguler.element`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) to find the `img` element and bind the event.

In your directive, it should be `element.find('img')`.

```
angular.module('Joy', [])
    .directive('hello', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, ele) {
            var img = ele.find('img');
            console.log(img);
            img.bind('load', function () {
                console.log('img is loaded');
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="Joy">
    <div hello>
        <img ng-src="https://www.google.com.hk/images/srpr/logo11w.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

---

#### Update 1

If use `ng-repeat`, add a `$timeout` to wait for `ng-repeat` finishes first. Check working demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xqywjghp/1/).

Note: this demo is loading a very large image. After the image is loaded, the text `img is loaded` will be shown.

#### Update 2

If the event binding is not working, try native `image.onload` binding (or `oncomplete` to find images cached). Working demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xqywjghp/3/).

Comment: Thank you. Does it matter if the img tag itself uses other directives (another 3rd party module)? 

I added this code to the main directive (rn-carousel in my example above)
```
restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
         var sliderimg = element.find('img');
          sliderimg.bind('load',function()
          {
                console.log ("*** IMAGE FULLY LOADED");
          });
but this does not get called

Comment: Thank you. I have accepted your answer as it works based on the question I asked. What is happening however in my case is this is a slider carousel - and the code I've added to this part: https://github.com/revolunet/angular-carousel/blob/master/dist/angular-carousel.js#L26 does get called (same code as yours), but only for the first image. If I move to another image, it does not get called. Can you think of why this may be?

Comment: Em, seems strange. I use native `image.onload` event here: http://jsfiddle.net/xqywjghp/3/. Please check whether working at your side.

Comment: thank you. For some reason, both .onload and .bind are only called for the first image in the angular-carousel library. I edited it to add both the .onload and .bind after this line: https://github.com/revolunet/angular-carousel/blob/master/dist/angular-carousel.js#L26 --> they both get called for the very first image but as the subsequent images get loaded they never get called